# Rails unknown format on AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, remotipart

I'm trying to implement a very simple file form using the `remotipart` gem. Most of my files are the exact same as the tutorial ones:

timeline.html.erb :

```
<%= form_tag new_feed_path(:format => "js"), remote: true, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :brief_id, @brief.id %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

briefs_controller.rb

```
 def new_feed
    puts params
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
 end
```

new_feed.js.erb

```
alert('success!');

<% if remotipart_submitted? %>
  alert('submitted via remotipart')
<% else %>
  alert('submitted via native jquery-ujs')
<% end %>
```

But everytime I submit the form, I get the following error in the logs:

```
Processing by ResourcesController#create as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 14ms
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
```

Did I miss something ? I know ajax file upload can be tricky on RoR, but remotipart seems to be a viable solution.

**EDIT** I managed to fix the first issue by adding `:format => "js"` , but now I face another problem: none of the form datas are sent. In fact, here are the sent params:

```
{"controller"=>"briefs", "action"=>"new_feed"}
```

Comment: You have used remote true but request is still processing as HTML, as your logs saying

Comment: Hm, what about changing the name of news_feed.js.erb to create.js.erb?  Other suggestion would be to put the call to `authorize` within the `respond_to` block above.

Comment: @BenPolinsky , the js file works just fine, authorize too . I'm pretty sure it comes from the form_for itself, but no idea how or why

Comment: show your rake routes | grep new_feed

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi new_feed POST /new_feed(.:format) briefs#new_feed

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example from [Remotipart's docs](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart#example).

Looks like you're not passing `:html => { :multipart => true }` to `form_for`

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<%= form_tag new_feed_path, html: {multipart: true }, method: :post, remote:true do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :brief_id, @brief.id %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

**edit**

try it

install this gem `pry`

[RailsCast Pry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

briefs_controller.rb

```
def new_feed
  binding.pry #just to be sure that this action is not called 
  puts params
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'new_feed') # modify this
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't work. It worked when I replaced it by ```form_tag new_feed_path(format: :js)``` , but with two major issues:
- form doesn't send file data
- remotipart is not used ( I get the ```'submitted via native jquery-ujs'``` message)

Comment: if there more lines in the rails logging please add in your post.